# How would I visually alter only the Capital letters in my editor?

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-code

I find camel case difficult to read at times and have been scouring the internet for a way to be able to specifically alter the visual appearance of strictly the capital letters in camel/pascal case words. (I'd like to try such things as spacing, bold/regular, underlining, etc...)

I understand this seems trivial and meaningless but since I delved into [this conversation](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=20533923) as well as the [associated](https://eyeondesign.aiga.org/sad-but-true-comic-sans-might-just-be-the-best-font-for-dyslexics/) - [links](https://bdatech.org/what-technology/typefaces-for-dyslexia/) I've been noticing my brain hates the way it reads and it takes a few ms for my brain to process it over using snake case (which I can't just use for everything, understandingly)

Comment: What do you mean by "alter the visual appearance of strictly the capital letters in camel/pascal case words"?

Comment: I just want to apply conditional formatting to the capitals in camel/pascal case names, *(ie. make bold or underline or re-color only the `C` in `camelCase` or the `P` and `C` in `PascalCase`)* I don’t know what I want to do yet *(whether I want to make them bold or not, or underline or not)* until I can see it in the editor)*

Comment: What you want is a *font* that suits your purpose, which is unclear.

Comment: Currently, there is no extension that provides this sort of functionality, however, one could be built to do this. It is well with in the abilities of the VS Code API.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, (AToW ***2022/05/21***) there is no extension that provides the functionality that you are asking for, however; it is well with-in the bounds of the V.S. Code API one could be built to do this. It is well with in the abilities of the **[VS Code API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api)**.

There is likely more than one way to skin this cat, but personally, I would start by using regex that would target the *`camelCase`* & *`PascalCase`* variables, that would be injected via a *"JSON-formatted"* **[TextMate grammar *(tm link)*](https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars)** (also sometimes referred to as a **["VSC-TM Grammar" *(vsc link)*](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#contributing-a-basic-grammar)**).